# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-conf-volume-driver" : configmap "spark-drv-27c9b887c306cb9c-conf-map" not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, scala-spark

I am trying to run scala distributed code using spark-submit with cluster mode in minikube.
1.I used this dockerfile

```
FROM datamechanics/spark:2.4.6-hadoop-3.1.0-java-8-scala-2.12-python-3.7-dm18

WORKDIR /opt/application
RUN mkdir /tmp/data-pvc
COPY target/DisDPMM_2_13-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar .
```

2.I create namespace, serviceacount and rolebinding

```
kubectl create namespace spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
kubectl create serviceaccount spark-editor --namespace=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
kubectl create rolebinding spark-edito-role --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo:spark-editor
```

3.In addition,I create StorageClass, PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim
StorageClass:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: spark-local-dir-v1
  namespace: spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

PersistentVolume :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: spark-local-dir-pv
  namespace: spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: spark-local-dir-v1
  local:
    path: /mnt/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
```

PersistentVolumeClaim:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: spark-claim
  namespace: spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: spark-local-dir-v1
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

by the end i submit my job using spark-submit

```
spark-submit \
    --master k8s://$KUBERNETES_MASTER\
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name DisDPMM \
    --class my_code.DisDPMM\
    --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-editor \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark_kubernetes_concepts_demo:latest \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-pv.options.claimName=OnDemand\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-pv.options.storageClass=spark-local-dir-v1\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-pv.options.sizeLimit=10Gi\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-pv.mount.path=/mnt/data\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-pv.mount.readOnly=false\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.context=minikube\
    local:////opt/application/DisDPMM_2_13-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

end i get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSHcm.png)
the logs in the pod:

```
Unsetting extraneous env vars (UTC): 14:14:00
Finished unsetting extraneous env vars (UTC): 14:14:00
++ id -u
+ myuid=185
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
+ set +e
++ getent passwd 185
+ uidentry=
+ set -e
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -w /etc/passwd ']'
+ echo '185:x:185:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false'
+ SPARK_K8S_CMD=driver
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ shift 1
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'
+ env
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
+ sort -t_ -k4 -n
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
+ readarray -t SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ PYSPARK_ARGS=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ R_ARGS=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' 3 == 2 ']'
+ '[' 3 == 3 ']'
++ python3 -V
+ pyv3='Python 3.7.13'
+ export PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.13
+ PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.13
+ export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
+ PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
+ export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
+ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@")
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=10.244.0.30 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class my_code.DisDPMM local:////opt/application/DisDPMM_2_13-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
23/04/27 14:14:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: can you add the output of `kubectl get rolebinding -n spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo`?

Comment: I get this response `No resources found in spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo namespace.`

Answer (score 0):

Most object in Kubernetes are namespaced, that does not include things like `serviceAccount`, but it does include `roles` and `roleBindings` as opposed to `clusterRoleBinding` and `clusterRole` which are - as the same says - cluster scoped.
Now, let's look at your commands.

First your are creating a namespace:

```
kubectl create namespace spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
```

Then you create a serviceAccount:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount spark-editor --namespace=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo
```

The last step is the responsible for the issue, that you are facing:

```
kubectl create rolebinding spark-edito-role --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo:spark-editor
```

You are creating a `roleBinding` so an object that is scoped to the namespace that it is created in, regardless if the subject is a cluster scoped object like a `clusterRole`. Hence, you created the `roleBinding` in the namespace that was currently selected, not your new namespace, hence you have permission issues, when `spark-submit` wants to perform actions in the namespace you created.

Your options are

1. delete the `roleBinding` that you have and amend the creation command with a namespace like so:

```
kubectl create rolebinding spark-edito-role --namespace=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=spark-kubernetes-concepts-demo:spark-editor
```

2. edit the existing `roleBinding` to change the namespace it lives in.

Comment: It doesn't work in my case.